# Software skills needed to learn Windows Phone 8?

Tags: mobile, windows-8, windows-phone

Assuming that a person is familiar with C#, ASP.NET, database technologies and basics of Windows 8 as well as Windows Store app development, what would be the software skills requirements needed to learn Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew C# a bit... My first WP app took 2 or 3 days. Then I submitted it to Marketplace. There was absolutely nothing special to deal with. I just did it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most important for you is to know windows phone 8 SDK.

[the WP8 SDK download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Comment: It's not for me per se. Say a course structure is being outlined by somebody intending to teach, then what would a student need to know beforehand?

Comment: If you have know the development of windows 8 metro style, you can directly to create apps on WP8, because they have the some kernal.
But, if you want to create apps on WP7(7.5), you also need to learn some knowledge of Silverlight.